# Clickhouse Data Import

Tags: database, clickhouse

I created a table in Clickhouse:

```
CREATE TABLE stock
(
    plant Int32,
    code Int32,
    service_level Float32,
    qty Int32
) ENGINE = Log
```

there is a data file

```
:~$ head -n 10 /var/rs_mail/IN/qv_stock_20160620035119.csv
2010,646,1.00,13
2010,2486,1.00,19
2010,8178,1.00,10
2010,15707,1.00,4
2010,15708,1.00,10
2010,15718,1.00,4
2010,16951,1.00,8
2010,17615,1.00,13
2010,17616,1.00,4
2010,17617,1.00,8
```

I am trying to load data:

```
:~$ cat /var/rs_mail/IN/qv_stock_20160620035119.csv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSV";
```

and I get an error

```
\n2010: 7615,1.00,13ion: Cannot parse input: expected , before: 2010,646,1.00,13

Row 1:
Column 0,   name: plant,         type: Int32,   ERROR: text "2010,64" is not like Int32

: (at row 1)
```

what am I doing wrong?

File: https://yadi.sk/d/ijJlmnBjsjBVc

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but I would look into what the FORMAT CSV uses for default delineation, maybe it is not a `,`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thank you uYSIZfoz:

> Your file has BOM (EF BB BF bytes at begin).

In my case was a BOM in the header row of the original file. I simply excluded from loading the first line using the format CSVWithNames.

> cat /tmp/qv_stock_20160623035104.csv | clickhouse-client
>   --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSVWithNames";

Answer (score 3):

Int8 type has range -128..127.
2010 (first value) is out of range of Int8.

If you change table definition, everything is Ok:

```
$ clickhouse-client 
ClickHouse client version 0.0.53720.
Connecting to localhost:9000.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 1.1.53981.

:) CREATE TABLE stock
:-] (
:-]     plant Int16,
:-]     code Int16,
:-]     service_level Float32,
:-]     qty Int8
:-] ) ENGINE = Log

CREATE TABLE stock
(
    plant Int16, 
    code Int16, 
    service_level Float32, 
    qty Int8
) ENGINE = Log

Ok.

0 rows in set. Elapsed: 0.002 sec. 

:) Bye.
$ mcedit qv_stock_20160620035119.csv

$ cat qv_stock_20160620035119.csv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO stock FORMAT CSV";
$ clickhouse-client 
ClickHouse client version 0.0.53720.
Connecting to localhost:9000.
Connected to ClickHouse server version 1.1.53981.

:) SELECT * FROM stock

SELECT *
FROM stock

┌─plant─┬──code─┬─service_level─┬─qty─┐
│  2010 │   646 │             1 │  13 │
│  2010 │  2486 │             1 │  19 │
│  2010 │  8178 │             1 │  10 │
│  2010 │ 15707 │             1 │   4 │
│  2010 │ 15708 │             1 │  10 │
│  2010 │ 15718 │             1 │   4 │
│  2010 │ 16951 │             1 │   8 │
│  2010 │ 17615 │             1 │  13 │
│  2010 │ 17616 │             1 │   4 │
│  2010 │ 17617 │             1 │   8 │
└───────┴───────┴───────────────┴─────┘
```

Please note, that Int16, which I specified, could be also not enough for your data. Then specify Int32, Int64...

Comment: I tried to change the type to Int16 to send the first post. The error persists. It is possible that something is wrong with the encoding of a file? I corrected my question, because the error is the same.

Comment: I added a file that is trying to load

Comment: $ head -n1 test.csv | xxd 
0000000: efbb bf32 3031 302c 3634 362c 312e 3030  ...2010,646,1.00
0000010: 2c31 330d 0a                             ,13..

Comment: Your file has BOM (EF BB BF bytes at begin).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What if I use windows? When I run in CMD I get           
         "'cat' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: @Geobo You should know that ClickHouse only runs on Linux Ubuntu and some others OS, excluding Windows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the commas in this ruining the format

`2010,646,1.00,13`

Try to remove all the commas, then try to insert it back in as an Int.