# Importing from MySQL dump to Clickhouse

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-16.04, clickhouse

I want to import from MySQL dump to Clickhouse. I've tried going through the [official docs](http://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/) but cannot find anything. I've tried importing using CSV following [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954203/clickhouse-data-import). Any help appreciated. I've an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On small data, the export to tsv will work but at large it will not work, because only export will take a lot of time.

In this case, you need to import directly from stdout and clickhouse knows how to do it perfectly.

Example code:

```
mysql -u user  -ppass --compress -ss -e "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >0  AND id <=1000000" db_name | sed 's/\"//g;s/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/' | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO db_name.table FORMAT CSV"
```

Using this method, I import 500 GB and 1,9 billion rows in 7-10 hours in a clickhouse

Answer (score 2):

You can export data from MySQL into TSV file using MySQL command line:

```
mysql -Bse "select * from TABLE_NAME" > table.tsv
```

And then import data to ClickHouse:

```
cat table.tsv | clickhouse-client --query="INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME FORMAT TabSeparated"
```

Comment: Thanks @mikhail, is there no direct approach available to import a SQL to Clickhouse?

Comment: What does 'no direct approach' mean?

Comment: By direct approach I meant without first converting it into a TSV file

Answer (score -1):

My SQL data dump can be done by the following query:

```
mysql --protocol tcp -u clickhouse_user_name -p -P 9004 your_db_name < data.sql
```